# Bottom margin causing RecyclerView to re-order

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I just came across a strange issue. I'm trying to add margin to the bottom of my `RecyclerView`, but if I do so the items in my `RecyclerView` gets messed up (in the wrong order).

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtEmptyAdapter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="@string/myString" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rvContainer"
    >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/frag2recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            >

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried adding `android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"`  to `rvContainer` and to `frag2recycler` and both give me the same issue.

When I remove the margin then issue doesn't appear.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you check with `RecyclerView` `layout_height="wrap_content"` ??

Comment: it's a really bad code, try to imporve, both start and end margin does same job, the issue you're facing might be cause of match parent, try to make it as wrap_content, if this does'nt work add screenshot of the screen

Comment: test case try `android:clipToPadding="false"` in `RecyclerView`

Comment: @AshishSharma What exactly is bad code? `both start and end margin does same job` that simply is not true and adding `wrap_content` did not work.

Comment: I tried it and still the same issue.

Comment: @ClassA my mistake start and left & end and right does same job but for rtl purpose we prefer end and start, by default visibility is visible no need to add that, and at last add screenshot of your abnormal recyclerview behaviour

Comment: @ClassA did u solved it?

Comment: The layout didn't cause the issue, I will be deleting the question, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/frag2recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:paddingBottom="100dp"
            >
```

hope this helps